# Smoke not rendered in viewport in smoke and fire simulation

Tags: 3d-view, smoke-simulation, fire

So i have been messing around with the flame and smoke simulation, but for some reason, i cant seem to be able to see my smoke being rendered in my viewport. Here are my settings for the simulation.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eYol3CTmPgM]So i tried adding material to the domain, not sure if im doing it right but it certainly doesnt seems to be working right

Also i do all this following this tutorial [enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eYol3CTmPgM) but the result i get as you see here is completely different.

Comment: did you add a material to your domain?

Comment: Just tried adding material to the domain, but the effects just looks weird, i uploaded a photo of the setting for my materials, not sure if im doing it right tho.